# Programmatically save an outlook email as eml file

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, eml

Anyone has an idea that i save an outlook email as eml file, programmatically ?

Im currently reading this documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview

Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

The Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for saving messages as eml files (or getting streams). The best what you could do is to use Graph API where you could get the EML content, see [Get MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) for more information.